# what is wrong with my makefile code?

Tags: unix, makefile

I have a makefile that I needed to change around, and use it to install the program.  I can;t figure out why I am getting this error:

```
v245-2% make install
install -m 555 audit /export/home/student/scort323/bin
sh: install: not found
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `install'
```

Below is my code, can somebody please give me some advice.  I am not good at makefiles so trying to find this error is hard for me until I get a better understanding:

```
# Make file for audit
# Location to install binary. Default is /usr/local/bin. You may
# prefer to install it in /usr/bin or /sbin
BINDIR  = /export/home/student/scort323/bin
#BINDIR=/usr/bin
#BINDIR=/usr/sbin

# Location to install man page. Default is /usr/local/man. You may
# prefer to install it in /usr/man
MANDIR  = /export/home/student/scort323/bin
#MANDIR = /usr/man

# Compiler to use
CC      = gcc

# Linker to use
LD      = gcc

# Preprocessor options
CPPFLAGS = -DGETOPTLONG

# Compile and link options
# On a.out systems you might want to add -N when linking
# RPM_OPT_FLAGS can be set by rpm tool
# ...For production code
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O3 $(RPM_OPT_FLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -s
# ...For debug
#CFLAGS = -Wall -g
#LDFLAGS = -g

audit:  audit.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o audit audit.o

audit.o: audit.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c audit.c

install: audit
    install -m 555 audit $(BINDIR)
#/audit
    install -m 444 audit.1 $(MANDIR)
#/man1/audit.1

clean:
    $(RM) audit audit.o core *~ results

# check in
ci:     clean
    -ci -l *

dist:   clean
    cd .. ; tar --exclude RCS -czvf audit-0.2.tar.gz audit-0.2
```

Comment: Try `which install`, and tell us the result.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `install` utility, or you hosed your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the makefile. Check if you have install utility

$~ install --help

If you dont have then you can get it from GNU coreutils. If you have install somewhere then export its path in PATH variable

export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/install-utilit